# Bash script - Retrieve every value that fills *

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that's like

```
for i in /path/to/file/*.in; do
    ./RunCode < "$i" 
done
```

I want to be able to capture the output in something like *.out, with * being the same as *.in. How can I retrieve the text that * is expanded into so that I can reuse it?

Comment: You already have it, it's `$i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change file suffix with bash:

```
for i in /path/to/file/*.in; do
  ./RunCode < "$i" > "${i%.in}.out"
done
```

From `man bash`:

```
${parameter%word}
${parameter%%word}

Remove matching suffix pattern. The word is expanded to produce a 
pattern just as in pathname expansion. If the pattern matches a
trailing portion of the expanded value of parameter, then the result
of  the  expansion is the expanded value of parameter with the shortest
matching pattern (the ``%'' case) or the longest matching pattern
(the ``%%'' case) deleted. If parameter is @ or *, the pattern removal
operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the
expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an array variable
subscripted with @ or *, the pattern removal operation is applied
to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant
list.
```

Comment: Ah I just wasn't looking for the right thing in the manual. This is great, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

By the wording in your question (could be clearer), I assume you wish remove the leading path.

You can use [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to accomplish what you want:

```
out_dir="/path/out"
for i in /path/to/file/*.in; do
    name="${i##*/}"
    ./RunCode < "$i" > "$out_dir/${name%.in}.out" 
done
```

This will remove the leading path and the `.in` extension, name all output files with `.out` extension, and place them in the directory `/path/out`.

- `${i##*/}` - Removes all leading characters through the last occurrence of `/` to get the name of the file with the `.in` extension.
- `${name%.in}.out` - Removes the trailing `.in` extension from `name` and replaces with `.out`.

Comment: I actually wasn't looking to remove the leading path, but that's really helpful. I marked the other answer because it's what I was actually looking for, but I upvoted you. Thanks!